# Angular 10 Reload After Delete

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to refresh after an item is deleted from my json server. It successfully deletes the item, but I have to refresh the page to see that the item has been deleted. I tried doing a reload from html when the delete button is push, no luck there.  I know I want to re-load the item again that way it would show the item no longer exist.

I tried call to the "get" again but got a lot of errors trying to use subscribe and from my research using subscribe inside subscribe is not a good approach. I don't want to actually do a page reload just a realistic way to call my get function which actually is responsible for showing the items on my view.

Here is my delete inside my service.

```js
RemoveProductFromWishlistItem(id:number): Observable<void>{
         console.log("Remove from wishlist item");
           return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.wishlistitemUrl}/${id}`)
     
           .pipe(catchError(_err => of (null))
         );
     
}
```

Thanking You In Advance
PH

Comment: How are you updating local scope? You don't really need to do another GET. Just update the local data.

Comment: use switchMap to get the updated wishlist after delete: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

#### 1st Approach: Observables and Subscriptions

When the content loads at first, and you subscribe to the .get()'s observable, you could store the subscription and unsubscribe from it when you want to refresh the page.

```js
// items-list.component.ts

private subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit(){
    this.loadPosts();
}

loadPosts(){
    this.subscription = this.service.getItems().subscribe(items=>{
        this.items = items;
    });
}

// called by a button click
onDelete(id){
    this.service.deleteItemById(id).subscribe(()=>{
        if(this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.loadPosts(); // reload all posts from the server
    });
}
```

2nd Approach: Promises

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.loadPosts();
}

async loadPosts(){
  try{
      this.posts = await this.service.getPosts().toPromise()
  } catch(e){ 
      console.error(e); 
  }
}

onDelete(id){
   this.service.deleteById(id).subscribe(()=>{
       this.loadPosts();
   })
}
```

#### 3rd Approach: update changes locally

You can simply remove the deleted item from the local list, thus saving ourselves from a lot of unnecessary network usage. But be aware of the case when somebody else modified the list in the meantime.
There are two methods

- Update content first and then make a delete request assuming that it would succeed. This could make your application feel responding faster, but it can result that the user sees that the item has been removed while it is not removed from the server.
- Delete content from the server and update the view when it finishes.

```
onDelete(id){
    let deletedElement, deletedIndex;

    items.forEach((element, index) => {
        if(element.id == id) {
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
            deletedelement = element;
            deletedIndex = index;
        }
    });

    this.service.deleteItem(id).catch(e=>{
        // restore deleted element
        this.items.splice(deletedIndex, 0, deletedItem); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, add a switchMap to refetch the data after delete, so something like this:

```
RemoveProductFromWishlistItem(id:number): Observable<WishlistModelHere>{
  return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.wishlistitemUrl}/${id}`).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.getWishlist()),
    catchError(_err => of (null))
  );
}
```

I've used dummy names here as we don't know what your model is called (named it `WishlistModelHere` ) and getting the wishlist I named `getWishlist`.

Depending on how you want to handle this, you can also do the switchMap in the component, here I just chained it in the service after the delete. Either way works.